# Selective client side validation in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, client-side, data-annotations

How can I implement selective client side validation
 using  MVC 2 built-in validation system?

Assume I have a checkbox in my form title "Do you have any child?"
 and if checked the textbox below it should be required
 (textbox titled Number of children).

Comment: This also applies to more common scenarios such as having a cancel button on the form - obviously you do not want validation to fire then.

Answer (score 0):

A few options that might get you thinking here.  In the case of multiple post actions (e.g. clicking cancel button on a form shouldn't fire validation) I have made sure that forms only post one actions and anything else is essentially a styled link.  Validation won't fire in this case.

If, as is in your case, you have complex validation I would suggest creating a custom validator and registering a client side adapter e.g.

```
[RequiredIfHasChildren]
```

So you'd be writing a custom validation attribute, a custom model validator and some JavaScript code to register a new client side validator.  This sort of approach has worked for me in the past but the dependency on another model property can be a bit of a problem.

Hopefully this helps.